# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down. How to handle a connection pool exception inside multithread application?

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling, amazon-sqs

My application is creating multithread to read messages from SQS here

```
new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                readMessages();
            }
        });
```

The readMessage  method has functionality like this

```
 public void readMessages() {
       ........

       Object messages = new ArrayList();
       try {
          slingshotMessage = (new ReceiveMessageRequest()).withQueueUrl(this.queueUrl)
                            .withWaitTimeSeconds(this.subProps.getWaitTimeSeconds())
                          .withVisibilityTimeout(this.subProps.getVisibilityTimeoutSeconds())
                         .withMaxNumberOfMessages(this.subProps.getMaxNumberMessages());
           messages = this.sqs.receiveMessage(slingshotMessage).getMessages();
           
        } catch (Exception var6) {
            log.error("An error occurred while reading messages for subscriber: '" + this.subProps.getSubscriberName() + "' queueUrl: '" + this.queueUrl + "'", var6);
        }

}
```

I see the exception is raised at `this.sqs.receiveMessage` inside read message() function. I am catching the exception here but when an error is thrown the log pile up with the repeated exception saying

````
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34) ~[httpcore-4.4.12.jar:4.4.12]
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:196) ~[httpcore-4.4.12.jar:4.4.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:268) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy37.requestConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:176) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1256) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1072) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.408.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2147) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2116) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2105) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1559) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1530) ~[aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.415.jar:na]
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.slingshot.subscriber.aws.AwsSubscriber.readMessages(AwsSubscriber.java:63) ~[slingshot-1.3.37-B3-RELEASE.jar:1.3.37-B3-RELEASE]
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.slingshot.subscriber.Subscriber.lambda$newSubThread$0(Subscriber.java:61) ~[slingshot-1.3.37-B3-RELEASE.jar:1.3.37-B3-RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]```
````

So my questions are

1. Is there a way how to solve connection pool exception?
2. As this is inside a newthread lambda it keeps on creating the thread, Is there a way I can silently exit with required stack trace and not piling up with the same error on logs.

Answer (score -1):

First of all dont create new threads for each and every message thats the bad idea.
Create one thread which keep poll your SQS and then send the retrieved data for further process to another thread using workstealing threadpool or some other pools.

Here is the pseudo code,

```
public final class AsyncThreadUtils {

    private static final ExecutorService WORKER_SERVICE = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

    private AsyncThreadUtils() {
    }

    public static void addTask(Runnable asyncThread) {
        WORKER_SERVICE.submit(asyncThread);
    }

    public static void stopAllThreads() throws InterruptedException {
        if (!WORKER_SERVICE.isShutdown() || !WORKER_SERVICE.isTerminated()) {
            WORKER_SERVICE.awaitTermination(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            WORKER_SERVICE.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}        
class DataConsumer implements Runnable {
        while(true) {
            // Get the message from SQS
            // If data received then give it to another thread for processing
            AsyncThreadUtils.addTask(data -> { 
                   // Process goes here.
});
            // sleep for some time like 400ms
        }
    }
     
        // Initiate above thread during the bootup of your program.
        Thread sqsDataConsumer = new Thread(new DataConsumer())
       sqsDataConsumer.start();
```

Before shutdown of your java process call the shutdown method of threadpool.

Comment: OP is *not* creating a new thread per message, and your code *is.*